# jquery element same class

Tags: jquery

I search a simple/clean way to get every element with the same classes than a selected element.

something like that (not working)

```
var myElement = $("#elementId");

var listSameClass = $.hasClass(myElement.attr("class"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest, if I understand properly:

```
var currentClass = this.className,
    allWithClass = $('.' + className);
```

This does assume that a single class is present, however.

For elements with multiple classes:

```
var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/).join('.'),
    allWithClass = $('.' + classes);
```

Somehow I'd not realised that you were selecting an element by its `id` first, in that situation I'd advise you use Matt's answer, since any correction would essentially turn my answer into a duplicate. Oops.

Comment: I like that, just use prop('class') instead of className. Tank you

Comment: You can, of course; but I don't see the point of using/creating a jQuery object in order to access something that's available in the native DOM.

Comment: my item is already a jquery element because I need other options.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is very simple:

```
var myElement = $("#elementId");
var classes = myElement.prop('class').split(/\s+/);
var classSelector = '.' + classes.join('.');
var otherElements = $(classSelector);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/58uQh

---

Not small enough? Let's make it into an unreadable one-liner!

```
var myElement = $("#elementId");
var otherElements = $('.' + myElement.prop('class').replace(/\s+/g, '.'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/PQ5fX/

Comment: `myElement.prop('className')` or `myElement.attr('class')` or does jQuery take care of this (I hope not)?

Comment: @FelixKling jQuery takes care of it. Either works with `.prop()`.

Comment: that what I was thinking at beginning, just want something smaller. but tanks

Comment: Mmmh, ok... I'm not really happy with this though :D ;)

Answer (score 0):

var myElClass = $(this).attr('class');
var $myEls = $(myEl).find(myElClass);

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: find take descending element, but with $.find. maybe that can work. I will check.

Comment: @forX please read the API docs more closely. There is no `$.find`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.find

Comment: You're right, forX, that was my mistake. You'd do something like $(body).find();